# How to rename YouTube videos in the playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I've created a YouTube playlist from 3rd party videos (uploaded to YouTube). Is there any way to rename these videos in my playlist? (The current names are too long, and not structured well.)

Comment: cant be done unless you download all videos from playlist, upload them as private (to avoid copyright alarm) and rename them as you desire

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, but there is absolutely no way to be able to do what you are asking, unfortunately.

This is due to the fact that if you are not the owner of a video, so those options are not allotted to you. Although I completely understand what you mean – and I certainly wish it were possible because I'd use it quite a bit.

If you cannot understand why this rule exists, imagine yourself uploading a cute video of your children to your account...then coming back three days later to see someone you don't even know has your video and has changed the title and make it theirs! That would be an (albeit dramatic) example of the types of things that prevents.

*However*, by following the instructions below, you will be able to change just about anything else including:

- Notes on each video in your playlist
- Arrangement of playlist videos
- Changing the names of the actual PLAYLIST (not video)
- Change default cover photo image for the playlist (although not for indicidual videos, either unless you own them).
- A few other management options.

I'm hoping that I could be of at least some help, and that you aren't too devastated, and that you might find a way to handle your issue via one the other personalization options that you *are* afforded on 3rd party videos!

#### Steps to Change Playlist Options

1. First and foremost, please go ahead and take a sec to confirm you're logged into YouTube.
2. Next, go ahead and go to [All Playlists](https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists)
3. Once there you will choose the Playlist you wish to edit. If you plan to edit several, it'd be easiest to start at the top so you don't lose track by jumping around.
4. You will find a settings button at the upper-right of the playlist, once you've selected one to edit. You will also have an arrow appear at the right-side of the video if you hover over it. If you click the arrow, you may change several things about the video or options regarding it and your playlist.